# ¿por qué declarar right: 0 y left:0 para que funcione margin?

Tags: html, css

Buscando en el sitio como centrar una imagen dentro de un div encontré lo siguiente:

```css
.Tarjeta{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border:5px solid pink
}
.Tarjeta img {
    position: absolute; /* se usa en caso de este div, donde tiene la altura y el ancho definido, sin esto top, right y left no funcionarían */
    width: 100px;
    top: 25%; /* sirve en caso de un div como este, donde tiene una altura definida, en caso de que la altura no este definida esta edición no se pone ; */
    right: 0; /* se debe usar para que margin 0 auto funcione */
    left: 0; /* se debe usar para que margin 0 auto funcione */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Esto lo centra */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedorTarjetas">
        <div class="Tarjeta">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="Tarjeta">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="Tarjeta">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg" alt="" >
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Y la duda que me surgió fue por que hay que declarar right: 0 y left:0 para que funcione margin? y por que las cajas (contenedorTarjetas) tienen un pequeño espaciado?, hay forma de sacarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empecemos que el hecho de usar **`position`** con un valor de `absolute` saca al elemento del flujo *normal o regular* que tiene, es decir ya no se acomodará donde por declaración le tocaba.

Ahora como tiene esa posición, entonces el único modo de moverlo es con las claves:

- top
- bottom
- left
- right

Ahora:

- Puedes quitar la regla **`top: 25%;`** y esa misma declararla dentro del **`margin`** y tendrá el mismo efecto que es lograr que la imagen se separe del top un 25%
- **Me parece** debes generar esa mezcla de posicionamientos tanto con **`margin`** y `position` por que:

  - Tratas de acomodar un elemento cuya naturaleza es ***inline*** es decir que se acomoda uno a lado del otro
  - Si cambias dicha naturaleza a bloque en la clase que aplica para la imagen entonces ya no vas a requerir de posicionamientos y menos coordenadas de los extremos que le indiquen al elemento como acomodarse; dejando todo en manos de los valores que tu mismo le asignes a la clave **`margin`**

**OPCIÓN 1**

De hecho...

Basándonos en tu mismo código podemos hacer los siguientes cambios:

- Coloca a las imágenes un **`display`** con un valor de **`block`** ya que por default no lo son y el **`margin`** no funcionaría sobre ellas
- Quita tanto del **`div`** padre como de la imagen los valores siguientes:

  - **`position`** absoluta y relativa
  - valores asignados a las coordenadas de: **`top`**, **`left`**, **`right`** y **`bottom`**

Quedando así y consiguiendo el mismo resultado:

```
.Tarjeta{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border:5px solid pink
}
.Tarjeta img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 25% auto; 
}
```

**OPCIÓN 2 (LA MAS RECOMENDADA)**

Sin embargo sería mejor eliminar de tus reglas CSS lo siguiente:

- Display con el valor **`inline-block`**, todos los **`div`** por defecto son elementos en bloque y dado el escenario no parece *necesario que ahora tengan la capacidad de ser **`inline-block`***
- Quitar el position relative, de todos modos si lo único que deseas es acomodar la imagen, no tiene caso sacar del flujo de elementos al div contenedor
- En su lugar al contenedor padre declarale un `display` de tipo flex para que así los hijos o elemnentos internos sean cajas flexibles
- Como por default los elementos se van a acomodar de forma horizontal en el *main axis* basta con declarar el uso de justify-content con un valor de center para que el elemento interno que es la imagen quede *centrada* de su padre
- Si también deseas que el elemento se alinee en su eje horizontal o *cross axis* puedes emplear está regla `align-items` con un valor de `center`

Tus reglas CSS podrían quedar así:

```
.Tarjeta {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border:5px solid pink;
}
.Tarjeta img {
    width: 100px;
}
```

**REFERENCIAS**

- [módulo flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)